# package io.rsocket.core does not exist during maven build

Tags: java, maven, rsocket

I'm facing some strange problem.
During maven build I'm getting `package io.rsocket.core does not exist`.
My `pom.xml` contains following dependencies

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.rsocket</groupId>
        <artifactId>rsocket-core</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0-RC6</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.rsocket</groupId>
        <artifactId>rsocket-transport-netty</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0-RC6</version>
    </dependency>
```

Analyzing reactor-core jar file showes that there is no core package in that jar. Did I missed some dependencies?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Package is found in the artifact (spring-cloud-function-rsocket) Add this to your pom:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-cloud-function-rsocket</artifactId>
    <version>3.1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
 </dependency>
```